# Retrieve group events with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api

I'm a little confused trying to adapt to the new facebook Graph API.
Whereas before I would have used events.get, I'm not entirely sure what to use now!
I can't seem to get a list of a group's events through fql, nor through the Graph API itself.

Any pointers? Should I keep using REST?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/group/events

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation under "Connections" it doesn't appear that you can get /events. Or for that matter /albums or anything useful...

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group

Answer (score 1):

However, if you know that something is an event (which you could probably do because the link in the data has "eid" in it - I can't see a way beyond that) then you can call the event URL (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event) and get the details that way.